# Is it correct to say "to leave on the bus"

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to say

> to leave on the bus

I have heard to get off the bus or to leave the bus but have not heard to leave on the bus.

Comment: You can leave somewhere on a bus. You can call it 'the bus' if you mean a particular bus, or if you are talking about buses in general.

Comment: "Leave on the bus" and "leave the bus" are pretty much opposites.

Comment: You might leave one of your possessions on the bus.

Comment: If you take a bus from location one to location two, you've left (location one) on (via) the bus.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct in the sense of *departing on the bus*, Similar to *travelling on the bus*, and *arriving on the bus*. In all these constructions, *on the bus* tells us the mode of transport by which you departed, travelled or arrived. The use of “the” may refer to a particular bus but in this usage may also be nonspecific. *I went on the bike* may merely mean *I cycled there*.